# Spring Boot - Print interceptors with ordering

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a rest service developed using spring boot. I have imported a number of external libraries which have some interceptors. Is there a way to print the list of interceptors along with order in which they will be triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject all beans of given type (in that case you can use the `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` interface) in any of your components. So if you want to print(or do something else with) all interceptors you can do something like this:

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

   @Autowired
   private List<org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor> interceptors;

   @PostConstruct  //not required, but you can use it to print at the app startup
   public void printInterceptors() {
        //TODO use this.interceptors
   }
}
```

Also, I guess that Spring prints the interceptors on startup, maybe in the debug log.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but I got this exception:

`Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'interceptors'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor>' available...`

I added this interceptors code in my SpringBootServletInitializer application. Spring version 1.5.22.RELEASE.